# Spring Batch: Tasklet with Task-Executor

Tags: concurrency, spring-batch, executor

I have a problem understanding something. I am using Spring-Batch, configured tasklet with a task-executor. Few configuration on task-executor works fine, other configuration seems that the tasklets are not executed. I don't understand, why few of them let Spring-Batch work, but others keep it away from work. I hope someone will bring light into the dark.

What works is e.g.

```
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="10" queue-capacity="1000000" />

<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="10-50" queue-capacity="10000000" />
```

What doesn't work more and it looks like the threads doesn't start or got interrupt or not picked up:

```
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5-10" queue-capacity="10000000" />

<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5-10" queue-capacity="10" />

<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5-50" queue-capacity="10000000" />

<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="10-50" queue-capacity="1" />
```

The job is something like:

```
<batch:job id="myJob">
    <batch:decision ... />
    <batch:step id="myStep">
        <batch:tasklet task-executor="myExecutor">
            <batch:chunk reader="..." processor="..." writer="..." commit-interval="1000" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Maybe I am missing few basic knowledge about `task:executor`. How do I know, what are good values for `pool-size`, `queue-capacity`or similar. I guess when the configuration works fine on my system I don`t have that feeling to have guarantee that it works anywhere. What happens in the background, when it seems the job started, but then nothing happens more. I also can see under windows performance task manager, that the job doesn't do anything more.

Thanks for a clear explanation.

Comment: What is the class for your bean id: myExecutor ? Can you pls share your xml where you are defining myExecutor

Comment: Hi Guest, I am not sure what you mean, but "myExecutor" is already shown in the question. I didn't define a bean, I use what spring provides by default with `<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="..." queue-capacity="..." />`

Comment: You dont need to define but you need to specify/mention the specific taskexeutor implementation class

Comment: As I understand the doc, a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` will be created. See Spring-Documentation: [link-to-doc](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-namespace-executor)